# Website Template is not reloaded after some changes in custom module odoo

Tags: templates, odoo, e-commerce, qweb

I have custom module that inherits website product page and add some customization. Then, I want to remove some parts, and I removed and upgrade the module. Then, I checked this templated in settings> techinal > views > my view name. I found my changes are updated. But when. I go to the website product page , I got the error of removing part. How can I solve that?

Comment: And what is the error? And what is your customization code? Please add this info.